# MySQL Function: Selecting and returning column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I have a table Processes, which consists of an `ID (unsigned int, auto_increment)` and `Name (varchar, unique)`.

Selecting the following function with any input (whether in the table or not) always results in

> ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row

```
CREATE FUNCTION LookupOrInsertProcess(nametwo VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN
  DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
  SELECT ID INTO myid FROM Processes WHERE Name=nametwo;
  RETURN myid;
END$$
```

However, selecting the below function always returns NULL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LookupOrInsertProcess(nametwo VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN
  DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
  SELECT ID INTO myid FROM Processes WHERE Name=nametwo;
  RETURN myid;
END$$
```

Furthermore, please note that the following does return the correct result (numbers 30 and 50 are arbitrary):

```
CREATE FUNCTION LookupOrInsertProcess(nametwo VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN
  DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
  SELECT ID INTO myid FROM Processes WHERE Name=nametwo;
  IF myid IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 30;
  ELSE
    RETURN 50;
  END IF;
END$$
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Edited to remove clash between table column and function param. I don't believe that's the issue.

UPDATE2: Please note that the following appears to work, both when the input param is or is not in the table. Why, without the coalesce(), does the function return NULL even for input params which are in the table?

```
CREATE FUNCTION LookupOrInsertProcess(nametwo VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN
  DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
  SELECT ID INTO myid FROM Processes WHERE Name=nametwo;
  RETURN COALESCE(myid, 0);
END$$
```

Comment: try renaming the input parameter since it is the same as the column name and avoid differnt types of int. Use signed or unsigned.

Comment: Thanks. Renamed the input param. Made the declared var int unsigned. No change.

Comment: @iraxef Did you rename param in query too?

Comment: > Edited to remove clash between table column and function param. I don't believe that's the issue.

Problem was solved for me doing just that, if C is the name of a table column and you have a variable C in your function/procedure then the latter has the precedence, leading to fun results..

Answer (score 0):

Column names are not case-sensitive in MySql so you may find that `where Name = name` means 'give me every row'.

Try changing the input parameter to your procedure (and the corresponding condition in the query) to be `srchName` or something else different to `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename input `name` to different name like `inputName`.

Update:
Another suggestion.

```
DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
SET myid = (SELECT ID FROM Processes WHERE Name=nametwo);
RETURN myid;
```

Comment: The below still doesn't work:

    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LookupOrInsertProcess$$

    CREATE FUNCTION LookupOrInsertProcess(nametwo VARCHAR(255))
      RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
    BEGIN
      DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
      SELECT ID INTO myid FROM Processes WHERE Name=nametwo;
      RETURN myid;
    END$$